# Why doesn't my custom price add to the subtotal and grand total after adding to cart?

Tags: php, magento2, cart, observers

I want to add custom price for bundle products after adding to cart. I have used "checkout_cart_product_add_after" observer to do so. But it is adding custom price to product price, not in sub total and grand total.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <!-- Event for add to cart -->
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="customprice_observer_set_price_for_item_add" instance="Custom\Shop\Model\Observer\SetPriceForItem"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer class:

```
namespace Custom\Shop\Model\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;

class SetPriceForItem implements ObserverInterface
{
     public function execute(Observer $observer)
     {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
        if ($item->getProduct()->getTypeId() == Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
            foreach ($item->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $bundleitems) {
                if ($bundleitems->getProduct()->getTypeId() == Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
                    $bundle_price = $bundleitems->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
                    $fee = $bundleitems->getProduct()->getBuildInFee();
                    $final_price = $bundle_price + $fee;
                    $bundleitems->setCustomPrice($final_price);
                    $bundleitems->setOriginalCustomPrice($final_price);
                }
            }

            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }
        return $this;
     }
}
```

My price is not adding to subtotal and grand total.

Here is the cart item, subtotal and grand total.

[image]

Comment: add $bundleitems->save() after $bundleitems->setOriginalCustomPrice($final_price);

Comment: Same problem here, but with regular products. I am already executing `->save()` on the item - but it still has no effect on the sub totals and grand totals of the cart.